# a simple mailto: also fires postback on .net. How to prevent the postback?

Tags: .net, asp.net, mailto, dopostback

I've got a simple link

```
    <a   href="mailto:test@email.com">test@email.com</a>
```

Problem is in an asp.net page when using Internet Explorer 8 clicking on the link not only opens the email client but also navigates the url to `mailto:test@email.com`  i've tried adding `onclick="return false;"`
however this prevents the mailto: from firing at all. so nothing happens in this case.

i think the problem comes from a scriptmanager on the same page (which i kindof need)

again this only happens with IE. I havn't tested with previous versions of IE . But opera, ff, and chrome work just fine

just a quick edit. if i'm uisng a simple html page with IE8. it works just fine

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: `<div class="main">
            <script type="text/javascript"> some script here </script>
 
            
    <h2> Members 
     </h2>
            <a href="mailto:test@email.com">email</a>`

Answer (score 0):

It is firing postback because it is in `Anchor` so when you click on it try to find href link. You can use javascript or jquery to  solve this problem.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
                $('a').attr('href', '#');
            });
</script>
```